# Error using for_each and lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying to solve a simple Fibonacci problem using the lambda function, but I came across this error and I cant solve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    auto N{0};
    auto i{0};

    cout<<"Digite o valor de N desejado: ";
    getline(cin,str); //pega linha
    stringstream(str) >> N;

    if (N == 0){cout<<0;}
    else if (N == 1){cout<<1;}
    else
    {
        vector<int> v{0,1}; //cria vetor v

        for_each(v.begin(),N,
            [&](){
            v.push_back(v[i]+v[i+1]);
            i++;
        });

        i = 0;

        for_each(v.begin(),N,
            [&](){
            cout<<v[i];
            i++;
            });
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the error is the following:

```
quest1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: quest1.cpp:30:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘for_each(std::vector<int>::iterator, int&, main()::<lambda()>)’    });
    ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/algorithm:62:0,
                 from quest1.cpp:5: /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:3763:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter,
_IIter, _Funct)
     for_each(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Function __f)
     ^~~~~~~~ /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:3763:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: quest1.cpp:30:4: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_IIter’ (‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ and ‘int’)    });
    ^ quest1.cpp:38:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘for_each(std::vector<int>::iterator, int&, main()::<lambda()>)’
    });
     ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/algorithm:62:0,
                 from quest1.cpp:5: /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:3763:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter,
_IIter, _Funct)
     for_each(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Function __f)
     ^~~~~~~~ /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:3763:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: quest1.cpp:38:5: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_IIter’ (‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ and ‘int’)
    });
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

Comment: Second argument to std::for_each should be iterator not int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems in your code. One (already covered by other answers), you're passing the *number of iterations* as the second parameter to `std::for_each`, but it actually expects an *end iterator.* `std::for_each(a, b, f)` is designed to iterate from iterator `a` to iterator `b` and call `f` on each element in that range.

The second problem is more fundamental: if you modify the vector while iterating over it, you'll get Undefined Behaviour because any modification operation invalidates all iterators to the vector.

Looking at your code, it seems you want the first loop to a normal counting loop and not iteration over the container. The second loop could be done with `for_each` and a lambda:

```
vector<int> v{0,1};

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  v.push_back(v[i] + v[i+1]);
}

for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
  [](int element) {
    cout << element;
  }
);
```

Notice that the functor used in `for_each` is not nullary: the algorithm will pass the element to it.

Alternatively, the printing functionality could be implemented without lambdas:

```
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout));
```

Or, if you prefer to keep the loop, you could just as well use a range-based `for` loop instead of `for_each`. The code will be shorter and [subjective]easier to read[/subjective]:

```
for (int elem : v) {
  std::cout << elem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::for_each` requires (as the error tries to tell you) an iterator where to start looping and an iterator where to end. You however are passing an iterator and an `int`, which are "conflicting types". If you want to loop over an whole vector do something like that:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
std::for_each(v.begin(), // start at the front
              v.end(),   // loop over each element
              [&] (int& i) {
                i++;
              });
```

If you just need to loop over a part of the vector do that

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
std::for_each(v.begin(),       // start at the front
              v.begin() + 2,   // loop over the first two elements
              [&] (int& i) {
                i++;
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `for_each` function correctly. C++ does not know the signature you are using. Please refer to the documentation, e.g. [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/).

The compiler says exactly that. The second parameter of the `for_each` you are calling is of type `int&`, but the signature is `for_each(InputIterator, InputIterator, Function)` and not `for_each(InputIterator, int&, Function)`, so it fails to compile.